# Parse XML only particular node using SAX parser or fetch based on node

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am doing parsing of whole XML to make a form using call of these method:

```
 parser('a.xml');
```

I am using these method:

```
 function parser($file) {
    $parser = xml_parser_create();
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
    xml_set_object($parser, $this);

 //Specify element handler
    xml_set_element_handler($parser, 'start', 'stop');

//Specify data handler
    xml_set_character_data_handler($parser, 'char');

//Open XML file
    $file_pointer = fopen($file, 'r');

//Read data from the xml file
    while ($data = fread($file_pointer, 4096)) {
        xml_parse($parser, $data, feof($file_pointer)) or
                die(sprintf('XML Error: %s at line %d', xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($parser)), xml_get_current_line_number($parser)));
    }

//Free XML parser
    xml_parser_free($parser);
}
```

I am successfully doing parsing of full xml.

How to do parsing of a particular node in XML file without switching SAX parser.

Comment: I  suggest not using the old, event based SAX, but a more modern approach like XMLReader or DOM.

Comment: It is the requirement here @ThW